# Erro de um projeto Vue com Laravel

Tags: vue.js

O primeiro erro está dizendo que está nesse aquivo chamado `main.js`, sendo que não encontrei erro  nesse arquivo;

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import app from './app'

require('./bootstrap');


new Vue(app).$mount('#app');
```

esse é o erro:

Os números de erros são tão grandes que tive que colocar no repositório porque não cabia aqui

[Meu repositório](https://github.com/wladyband/erro/blob/master/erro%20vue.txt)

Preciso ver cada um deles.

Comment: Isso é por causa do `ESLINT`, ele esta avisando sobre os ponto e virgula. Basta tira-los e já vai sumir boa parte dos erros

Comment: Se o problema é dele então como faço para resolver o problema?

Comment: Apenas apague os `;` do seu codigo e pronto ;)

Comment: Valeu, estou corrigindo o código, só um minuto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como falei na resposta, para você resolver seus erros, comece tirando todos os `;` que possui. Ex:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import app from './app'

require('./bootstrap')

new Vue(app).$mount('#app')
```

E faça isso em todos os arquivos que você colocou `;`

[Aqui](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) tem um exemplo de configurações do `ESLint`

Para desativar o uso dele em um arquivo especifico (ex: `Bootstrap`), voce pode colocar isso no inicio do arquivo `/* eslint-disable */`.

Outras configurações adicionais você consegue ver no site a cima.

Comment: Só uma pergunta! eu retirei os pontos e virgulas no arquivo main.js depois executei novamente o projeto ele está pedindo para retira todo os pontos e virgulas do arquivo bootstrap.js.
A tecnologia  vue.js não usa ponto e virgula ?

Comment: A questão não é o `VueJS` e sim o `ESLINT` mas voce pode configura-lo para aceitar o `;`, vou editar minha resposta

Comment: muito obrigado, estou precisando muito de ajuda.

Comment: @wladyband editei

Comment: Eu entendi mais ou menos com desabilitar o ESLINT, mas eu vou fazer uma nova postagem para resolver esse problema.

Comment: @wladyband voce tambem pode criar um projeto sem o `ESLint`, sempre que vai criar o seu projeto, basta ficar de olho nas perguntas, vai ter uma que lhe pergunta se quer usar o `ESLint` é só colocar o `n` e  apertar `Enter`

Comment: Na vídeo aula o professor orienta em habilitar o ESLINT, agora é saber poque ele orienta em habilitar o ESLINT, você sabe para que serve?

Comment: eu acabei de colocar em todas as partes do projeto e onde colocquei a anotação ainda continua com o problema.   :(

Comment: Como falei o `ESLint` serve para voce evitar alguns padrões, então, você pode configura-lo, para dar erro sempre que seguir tal caminho, assim, evitar de ficar `Refaturando` o codigo.

Comment: vou criar o projeto sem o ESLINT e já te falo se consigo subir o projeto.

Comment: Beleza, fico no aguardo ;)

Comment: Acabei de criar a aplicação do zero sem o ESLINT e tive sucesso. Muito obrigado mesmo.